# Struggling to understand this code

Tags: ruby

I am following the interactive tutorials on rubymonk.com and have just started with lambda's which I feel I grasp reasonably well, however I am a bit lost with this code:

```
1  def with_names(fn)
2   result = []
3   [ ["Christopher", "Alexander"],
4     ["John", "McCarthy"],
5     ["Joshua", "Norton"] ].each do |pair|
6       result << fn.call(pair[0], pair[1])
7   end
8   result
9  end
10  l = lambda { |first_name, last_name| "#{first_name} #{last_name}" }
11  with_names(l)
```

Are the names entered between line 3's first `[` and line 5's `]` held in an array or a hash?  My understanding is that they are a hash of arrays and that when calling `.each do |pair| we are iterating through each array in the hash, is this correct?  In the next piece of code on line 6:

```
result << fn.call(pair[0], pair[1])
```

I believe that we are pushing each array element into the results array, although I'm not sure exactly how this code works especially  the `fn.call` part as I believe the `(pair[0], pair[1])` part is simply pulling the data in the index location of each array passed through the block.  A clear explanation of what is going on here would be much appreciated, I feel I am almost there with it.  Thanks.

Comment: it's surprising to see this code in a book, IMHO it's unidiomatic Ruby. I understand the use a weird lambda instead of a block to show the difference later, but that `each` should be a `map` and `pair` should be unpacked in the block arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Are the names entered between line 3's first `[` and line 5's `]` held in an array or a hash?

The name strings are held in arrays, all of which are contained in another "master" array. On looping through the "master" array, its elements (namely, `["Christopher", "Alexander"]`, etc.) will be passed to the block succeeding the `each` call.

---

In `fn.call(pair[0], pair[1])`, the lambda passed to the function is called with two arguments: the first and last name provided by the `each` iteration. This lambda is assumed to return some value. In this case, the lambda returns a concatenated string, so the expression partially evaluates to something like this:

```
result << "Christopher Alexander"
```

From here, the `<<` overloaded operator indicates that the right operand should be pushed onto the left operand (an array).

Comment: Thank you I think the main issue was I was getting confused by the .call and the hash/array question, thanks for breaking it down

Answer (score 1):

> Are the names entered between line 3's first [ and line 5's ] held in an array or a hash?

It is an array of arrays, i.e., each element of the array is another array which contains two strings.  So

```
result.first
=> ["Christopher", "Alexander"]
```

The lambda is a method which takes two arguments and formats them as a string.

> when calling `.each do |pair| we are iterating through each array in the hash, is this correct?

As I explained, there are no hashes here.  It is simply iterating over the array and each element is itself an array with two elements (the first name and last name).  `result` is filled with the return value(s) of the lambda method.